# Grails combining "in" and "isEmpty" inside and OR ignores "isEmpty"

Tags: hibernate, grails

I want to be able to write a criteria that allows me to search for all leads that either have a specific DevelopmentOfInterest(hasMany) or has none at all.

My domain model looks something like this :

```
Lead {
   Set<Development> developmentsOfInterest
   static hasMany = [
        developmentsOfInterest:Development
   ]
}
```

If I search for a specific list based on a list of developments I could use the following inside my criteria :

```
developmentsOfInterest{
    'in'("id", developments*.id)
}
```

To find all those without any developments I use the isEmpty

```
isEmpty("developmentsOfInterest")
```

So logic tells me if I then put these 2 together inside an OR I'd get the combined list..

```
or{
       isEmpty("developmentsOfInterest")
       developmentsOfInterest {
           'in'("id", developments*.id)
       }
 }
```

It doesn't.. It will only return the interested list (basically ignoring the "isEmpty")

The sql **generated** is as follows

`where (this_.account_id=? and (not exists (select 1 from lead_development where this_.id=lead_developments_of_interest_id) or (developmen1_.id in (?, ?))))`

But I assume this would be the correct sql command? It reads correctly:

`(not exists (select 1 from lead_development where this_.id=lead_developments_of_interest_id) or (developmen1_.id in (?, ?))`

Update :
I compared the SQL generated by isEmpty(), or sizeEq(), and the "in", and the "in" adds a whole bunch of extra query code with joins.. 
I'm guessing that the joins are incorrect, which causes the isEmpty to not work (as it will only display items that join with the developmentOfInterests)

```
where (this_.account_id=? and (? = (select count(*) from lead_development where this_.id=lead_developments_of_interest_id) or this_.id in (?))) order by lower(this_1_.first_name) asc limit ?
```

Account_id part of the filter criteria further up.
Can anyone help?
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

you can put your criteria as follows:

```
or{
   sizeEq 'developmentsOfInterest', 0
   'in' 'developmentsOfInterest', developments
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response.. If I use 
`or{
                    sizeEq 'developmentsOfInterest', 0
                    developmentsOfInterest{
                        'in'("id", allowedDevelopments*.id)
                    }
                }` 
it gives me the same result and if I use

                    `sizeEq 'developmentsOfInterest', 0
                    'in' 'developmentsOfInterest', allowedDevelopments`
I get a sql error 
No value specified for parameter 4. Stacktrace follows:
Message: No value specified for parameter 4

Comment: looks like you put this `sizeEq 'developmentsOfInterest', 0 'in' 'developmentsOfInterest', allowedDevelopments` into a single line :)

Comment: This is the SQL statement it generates:

`where (this_.account_id=? and (? = (select count(*) from lead_development where this_.id=lead_developments_of_interest_id) or this_.id in (?))) order by lower(this_1_.first_name) asc limit ?`

Is there  a way to see which params are being inserted? Because obviously param 4 is limit (which is fine) so i'm guessing the problem is params 1-3? Just don't know which one

Comment: no that was just me not formatting correcting :D definitely on separate lines

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question but I came across the same issue recently and I think the issue was that grails would default to an inner-join causing the isEmpty to be ignored

What worked for me was to explicitly specify the join type.

eg:

```
Lead.createCriteria().listDistinct {
createAlias('developmentsOfInterest', 'developmentsOfInterestJoin', JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN)

  or {
      isEmpty('developmentsOfInterest')
      inList('developmentsOfInterestJoin.id', developments)
  }
}
```